# extjs 5 Ext.draw.Container

Tags: extjs

I want to write a simple sample in extjs5 and use Draw Package.
according to [sencha doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/core_concepts/drawing.html) my code is:

1.index.html

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var contextPath = '<%=context%>';
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

<%--extJS--%>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= context%>/js/ext5/build/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/resources/ext-theme-neptune-all.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= context%>/js/ext5/build/ext-all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=context%>/js/extjspages/app.js"></script>
```

2.app.js

```
Ext.require("Ext.draw.Container");
```

Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',
    launch: function () {

```
    Ext.create('Ext.draw.Container', {
        sprites: [{
            type: 'circle',
            fillStyle: 'red',
            r: 100,
            cx: 100,
            cy: 100
        }],
        height:205,
        width:205,
        renderTo:Ext.getBody()
    });
}
```

});

but I catch an

> GET .../Ext/draw/Container.js?_dc=1403991476236 404 (Not Found) error

what is my wrong?
thank you

Comment: I know I have to load "sencha-charts" package in my code, but I don't know how can I load a package. In sencha cmd I can add "requires:["sencha-charts"] in app.json file but in my code I don't konw

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how to use sencha cmd. But you can add "sencha-charts" in index.html code using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= context%>/js/ext5/build/packages/sencha-charts/build/sencha-charts-debug.js"></script>
```